# Are Cryptonight lite and Cryptonight lite v1 the same?

Tags: cryptonight, aeon, cryptonight-lite

Are Cryptonight lite and Cryptonight lite v1 the same?

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not.

Cryptonight lite is a derivative of Cryptonight with two changes: a smaller memory usage (1 MB vs 2 MB) and half the loop iterations.

Cryptonight lite variant 1 is a modification of Cryptonight lite which adds a few operations to the main loop and the setup phase. The intent is to break existing ASICs to fight mining centralization. It is expected that Aeon will soon switch from Cryptonight lite to Cryptonight lite variant 1.